# Java HQL how to access objects after using a join

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy, hql

Trying to understand using joins with HQL.

```
def result=Food.findAll('from MealItems as m, Nutrition as n where m.food=n.food);
```

The result returns, but I'm not understanding exactly how/what it returns.
*Can I access the Nutrition object on each result?*

```
for(row in result){
     var ntr=row.nutrition;
     println ntr.calories;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you should read on hibernate.

It transforms the result set into list of object arrays. Utimately if its able to map the result to corresponding classes then it will do so.

Have a look at these links. It should help
[How hibernate works with HQL query if the Transformer is not explicit declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872920/how-hibernate-works-with-hql-query-if-the-transformer-is-not-explicit-declared)

http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/hql/joins.php

Comment: Looks like there is no way to do what I want (which is essentially like using a mysql join table) unless the domain classes explicitly share a property reference?

Comment: You can join tables with do not have a linkage at db level. But then you would get result as list of object array. I suggest you read on hibernate transform object which converts your object array to meaningful classes. I havent explored myself but that could help you further